# Конвертация из []float32 в **float32

Tags: c++, golang, type-conversion

Пытаюсь перенести библиотеку из с++ в go, сгенерировал обертку swig и появилась проблема.
Читаю файл модели как массив []float32 далее его нужно передать в функцию ожидающую **float, и вот какой правильный тип данных создать и как его передать я не знаю, пробовал `[]*float32{&model[0]}`, но не подходит так как тип []*float32.
В с++ был код:

```
auto model = ReadFile<float>(_MODEL_FILENAME); // model - std::vector<float> model

_models = {model.data()}; // model - std::array<const float *, 4UL>

_model_floats = {static_cast<std::uint32_t>(model.size())}; // model_floats - std::array<uint32_t, 4UL>

function(_handle, _TYPE, 0, 0, _models.data(),_model_floats.data()
```

Вот код go:

```
model, err_f := readFile(absPath) // model - []float32

models := ?

model_floats := uint(len(model))

function(conf.Handle, conf.Type, 0, 0, !models!, &model_floats) // Здесь models нужна конвертация в **float
```

Comment: Насколько я понял этот крестовый код (полное пернебрежение KISS-принципом вместе с ...) `_models` это массив указателей (из одного элемента) на массивы float (и в нем заполнен первый элемент), а `_model_floats` "параллельный массив" с размерами массивов, на которые указывают элементы из `_models`. И вот адрес  его первого элемента надо передать через адрес указателя на float (зачем так делать?) (суть понятна, (на ассемблере это было бы сделать совсем легко), но посколько на go я не пишу, то не знаю какие буковки тут надо набить, чтобы убедить компилятор в валидности адреса)

Comment: наверное, всё же `[][]float` в `**float`?

Comment: @PakUula Нужно именно []float32 в **float, библиотека не моя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно ручками собрать массив указателей.

Вот пример:

```go
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
void myfunc(float** data, uint64_t * sizes, uint64_t num_rows) {
    printf("Number of rows: %ld\n", num_rows);
    for (uint64_t i = 0 ; i < num_rows; i++) {
        for (uint64_t j = 0; j < sizes[i]; j++) {
            printf("%.6f ", data[i][j]);
        }
        putc('\n', stdout);
    }
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "runtime"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    data := [][]C.float{
        {
            1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,
        },
        {
            1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1,
        },
        {
            1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2,
        },
        {
            1.3, 2.3, 3.3, 4.3,
        },
    }
    data_ptr := make([]*C.float, len(data))
    sizes := make([]C.uint64_t, len(data))
    // Защищает указатели от сборщика мусора
    pinner := new(runtime.Pinner)
    for i, arr := range data {
        sizes[i] = C.uint64_t(len(arr))
        // Указатель на данные слайса
        ptr := unsafe.SliceData(data[i])
        // Сообщает сборщику мусора, что указатель ptr используется вне Go
        pinner.Pin(ptr)
        data_ptr[i] = ptr
    }
    C.myfunc(
        unsafe.SliceData(data_ptr), // аргументы С функций закрепляются автоматически
        unsafe.SliceData(sizes),
        C.uint64_t(len(sizes)),
    )
    // вернуть указатели под управление сборщиком мусора
    pinner.Unpin()
}
```

В этом примере функция `myfunc` принимает массив указателей на `float`, массив длин и общее число элементов в каждом массиве.

Для передачи данных в Си нужно извлечь указатели на данные каждого массива и сохранить их в массив указателей:

```
    data_ptr := make([]*C.float, len(data))
    for i, arr := range data {
        // Указатель на данные слайса
        ptr := unsafe.SliceData(data[i])
        // Сообщает сборщику мусора, что указатель ptr используется вне Go
        data_ptr[i] = ptr
    }
```

Слайс `data_ptr` превращается в указатель `**float` вызовом встроенной функции `unsafe.SliceData`.

Тут необходим один трюк. Так как в Go сборщик мусора работает параллельно с остальным кодом, может такое случиться, что данные по указателю `ptr` окажутся прибранными сборщиком мусора. Поэтому указатель `ptr` нужно "прибить гвоздями" в памяти. Для этого в `runtime` есть тип [`Pinner`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#Pinner) (начиная с Go 1.21) с методами `Pin(ptr)` и `Unpin`. Соответственно, в процессе извлечения указателей они закрепляются в памяти:

```
        ptr := unsafe.SliceData(data[i])
        // Сообщает сборщику мусора, что указатель ptr используется вне Go
        pinner.Pin(ptr)
```

Указатели закрепляются по одному, зато открепляются все чохом:

```
    // вернуть указатели под управление сборщиком мусора
    pinner.Unpin()
```

Результат работы программы:

```
Number of rows: 4
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000 
1.100000 2.100000 3.100000 4.100000 
1.200000 2.200000 3.200000 4.200000 
1.300000 2.300000 3.300000 4.300000
```

Comment: Спасибо, про процесс "прибития" не знал. Постоянная ошибка передачи в cgo Go pointer, из-за этого не могу сделать задачу.